# Limit Transformation in Gauss Quadrature

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

For a class homework, we have been asked to write code to evaluate a double integral of the form
$$\int_a^b\int_{\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)} f(x,y)dydx$$
Using the Gauss quadrature method. I understand the method itself, but since it requires the limits of integrations be $\pm1$, so for arbitrary limits I need a formula to alter the limits. In 1-D, I know that this formula is $$x=\frac{b-a}{2}u+\frac{b+a}{2}$$and then a simple variable change. I have looked, and I cannot find anything that gives a formula for doing this in 2-D, i.e. some formula of the form $y=c(u)$ such that $$\int_a^b\int_{\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)} f(x,y)dydx=\int_a^b\int_{-1}^1g(u)dudx$$ where g(x) is the transformed integrand. What is the form of this formula?

Answer (score 0):

For finite $\alpha$ and $\beta$?  Adapt the same formula.
$$ y = \frac{\beta(x) - \alpha(x)}{2} u' + \frac{\beta(x)+\alpha(x)}{2} $$